# How can i compare the user input values with the hard-coded values in HashMap?

Tags: hashmap, hashset, linkedhashmap

```
public static HashMap<String,Person> info = new HashMap<String,Person>();
public static HashMap<String,Person> input = new HashMap<String,Person>();

public void Data(){ 
    info.put("A1",new Person("A01","XYZ","Baseball",21,"USA"));
    info.put("A2",new Person("A02","ABC","Badminton",29,"AUS"));
    info.put("A3",new Person("A03","PQR","LawnTennis",25,"UK"));
    info.put("A4",new Person("A04","CDE","Football",28,"FRA"));      
}
```

Comment: Not entirely sure what you want to do, but the logical thing to do would be to convert user input into a Person instance, and then perform `info.values().contains(userInput)`.  Obviously you'd need to implement `equals()` and `hashCode()` in Person.  If you need to do this often, you might consider placing the same Person instances into a Set and checking the set.

Comment: I am trying to get the user values from the console and planning to save it in a new hashmap. later I need to compare the new hashmap values with the Existing(info) hashmap values and print it accordingly. if there is any mismatch in values than i need to ask the user to enter the valid input